# How can i run a query and pull information (x and y values) from the results of that query in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, sql, silverlight

I have a silverlight application that simply plots points on a graph. The points that it plots come from a sql query.

The silverlight program will have to run the query and pull the relevant data on its own.

How do i achieve this kind of functionality??

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say how many times it needs to plot the data per sec/min? Is it just to plot once. If so then when your app first loads write an asynchronous call and have the call query sql and return the results in the callback..

If the program needs to return data at set intervals then you'll need a dispatcher timer or something similar..

Ok something like this..

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
    }

private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var result = await UpdateGraphPoints();
        MyGraphPoints = this.PopulateTheGraph(result);
    }

    private async Task<List<MyGraphPoint>> UpdateGraphPoints()
    {
        var oper = await YourDatabaseQueryMethod();
        return oper;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyGraphPoint> PopulateTheGraph(object result)
    {

    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyGraphPoint> myGraphPoints;

    public ObservableCollection<MyGraphPoint> MyGraphPoints
    {
        get { return this.myGraphPoints; }
        set
        {
            myGraphPoints = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyGraphPoints");
        }
    }

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

}

```
public class MyGraphPoint : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int xValue;

    public int XValue
    {
        get { return xValue; }
        set
        {
            this.xValue = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("XValue");
        }
    }

    private int yValue;

    public int YValue
    {
        get { return yValue; }
        set
        {
            this.yValue = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("YValue");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your xaml - bind the MyGraphPoints observable collection to your graph control.

Comment: oh sorry, yes the data needs to refresh every once in a while but if i can just get the silverlight program to run the query and pull data from the results of that query that would be awesome

Comment: ok so you need to give me some more specifics like the actual query you're running and what the chart control is if its from Silverlight Toolkit etc. So if you fire the async call with the sql query inside the dispatcher timer and periodically callback. Store the results in an observable collection. You'll also need some mechanism to evaluation the changes to the graph possible. Doing this will make sure that your graph plots once and then depending on the timer interval updates You'll however, need to be more specific about the query and the bits above..

Comment: Most of the time the datastructure should be an observable collection which contains a set of datapoints with x and y values. Create that class or struct to store your sql results.

Comment: Ok, in order for me to give you as much information as i can i have to be at my other computer. I will update as soon as i can.. thanks for helping!

Comment: Unfortunately i can't get to my computer today. Can you give me some general idea of what i need to do? I'm honestly not sure what the query does.. it's pretty big and it accesses many tables from a database. The silverlight program displays data on silverlight line chart. The chart probably needs to update every 5 minutes give or take.

Comment: Ok cool i'll try to go through this and figure something out. The other thing i'm wondering is, how can my silverlight program access all the tables that the query requires?

Comment: the easiest way to do this is via a wcf service so write database call in here and then call wcf service asynchronously from your ssilverlight app

Comment: and from your wcf service you can use a orm layer. My personal preference is NHibernate but you can use entity framework as well - or just make a standard ado.net call.